# How do I replace micro's buffer function inside my serverless NextJS function running on Vercel?

Tags: node.js, next.js, stripe-payments, serverless, vercel

I have been following a [tutorial to secure my stripe webhooks in nextjs](https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/Stripe-Webhook-Verification-with-NextJS).
It recommends to use the npm package micro:

```
import { buffer } from "micro";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});
const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const buf = await buffer(req);
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }
```

Micro is by the people at Vercel. I am using Next.js + Vercel and when I check out [micros npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micro), it says:

> Disclaimer: Micro was created for use within containers and is not
> intended for use in serverless environments. For those using Vercel,
> this means that there is no requirement to use Micro in your projects
> as the benefits it provides are not applicable to the platform.
> Utility features provided by Micro, such as json, are readily
> available in the form of Serverless Function helpers.

However, I can't find the `buffer` function, that I am using in this example. Any ideas what i would have to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. This function does the same job:

```
async function buffer(readable) {
  const chunks = [];
  for await (const chunk of readable) {
    chunks.push(typeof chunk === 'string' ? Buffer.from(chunk) : chunk);
  }
  return Buffer.concat(chunks);
}
```

With this, there is no need to install a package.
[Source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/1294#issuecomment-969412409)

Comment: you would need to add the following below the next js route to get it working

`export const config = { api: { bodyParser: false } };`

Answer (score 1):

There unfortunately isn't a one-size-fits-all answer to this issue, as different factors come into play depending on the specific libraries, frameworks, and versions being used.

However, the good news is there's [a GitHub issue on Stripe's Node.js repo which provides many possible solutions](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/1294).  You can try each one until you find the one that works for you.